# Why do `(char)~0` and `(unsigned char)~0` return values of different widths?

Tags: c, char, unsigned-integer, integer-promotion, signed-integer

I bumped into this while writing a program trying to print the constituent byte values of UTF-8 characters.

This is the program that I wrote to test the various `~0` operations:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%x\n", (char)~0); // ffffffff
    printf("%x\n", (unsigned char)~0); // ff
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(char) == sizeof(unsigned char)); // 1
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(char) == sizeof(unsigned int)); // 0
    printf("%d\n", (char)~0 == (unsigned int)~0); // 1
}
```

I'm struggling to understand why `char` would produce an `int`-sized value, when `unsigned char` produces a `char`-sized value.

Comment: `%x` expects an `unsigned int`. So when you pass `-1`, it gets converted to the largest `unsigned int` (on a 2's comp machine). I don't know if that's standard, or just what happens here. Using `%hhx` would do the right thing. But using an unsigned type would make more sense.

Comment: If `char` is signed, `(char)~0` is probably converted to `(char)-1`. By the *default argument promotions*, that `(char)-1` is converted to `(int)-1`.

Comment: You cannot send a `char` through to `printf()`. It is automagically converted to `int` in the process of calling the function. When `char` is signed (such as in your implementation), `(char)~0` is a negative value. When a negative value is re-interpreted as `unsigned int` (when `printf()` processes the `"%x"`) it has a bunch of binary `1`s at the most significant bits.

Comment: More accurate version of my earlier comment: `%x` expects an `unsigned int`. So the `-1` you pass (as an `int` thanks to integer promotion) gets interpreted as an `unsigned int`, giving the largest `unsigned int` on a 2's comp machine. Using `%hhx` would do the right thing. But using an unsigned type (e.g. `unsigned char`) would make more sense.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `~0` would produce `(int)-1` (assuming 2's complement) so would be within the range of a signed `char`.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Ah, right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When passing a type smaller than `int` to a variadic function like `printf`, it get *promoted* to type `int`.

In the first case, you're passing `char` with value -1 whose representation (assuming 2's complement) is 0xff.  This is promoted to an `int` with value -1 and representation 0xffffffff, so this is what is printed.

In the second case, you're passing an `unsigned char` with value 255 whose representation is 0xff.  This is promoted to an `int` with value 255 and representation 0x000000ff, so this is what is printed (without the leading zeros).

Comment: When explained like this it makes total sense, it's an arithmetic promotion, not bitwise. I hadn't considered that at all. The signed char -1 is converted to signed int -1 and treated as an unsigned int for printing.

Answer (score 2):

They do not produce values of different widths. They produce values with different numbers of set bits in them.

In your C implementation, it appears `int` is 32 bits and `char` is signed. I will use these in this answer, but readers should note the C standard allows other choices.

I will use hexadecimal to denote the bits that represent values.

In `(char)~0`, `0` is an `int`. `~0` then has bits FFFFFFFF. In a 32-bit two’s complement `int`, this represents −1. `(char)` converts this to a `char`.

At this point, we have a `char` with value −1, represented with bits FF. When that is passed as an argument to `printf`, it is automatically converted to an `int`. Since its value is −1, it is converted to an `int` with value −1. The bits representing that `int` are FFFFFFFF. You ask `printf` to format this with `%x`. Technically, that is a mistake; `%x` is for `unsigned int`, but your `printf` implementation formats the bits FFFFFFFF as if they were an `unsigned int`, producing output of “ffffffff”.

In `(unsigned char)~0)`, `~0` again has value −1 represented with bits FFFFFFFF, but now the cast is to `unsigned char`. Conversion to an unsigned integer type wraps modulo *M*, where *M* is one more than the maximum value of the type, so 256 for an eight-bit `unsigned char`. Mathematically, the conversion is −1 + 1•256 = 255, which is the starting value plus the multiple of 256 needed to bring the value into the range of `unsigned char`. The result is 255. Practically, it is implemented by taking the low eight bits, so FFFFFFFF becomes FF. However, in `unsigned char`, the bits FF represent 255 instead of −1.

Now we have an `unsigned char` with value 255, represented with bits FF. Passing that to `printf` results in automatic conversion to an `int`. Since its `unsigned char` value is 255, the result of conversion to `int` is 255. When you ask `printf` to format this with `%x` (which is a mistake as above), `printf` formats it as if the bits were an `unsigned int`, producing output of “ff”.

Answer (score 1):

In these both calls

```
printf("%x\n", (char)~0); // ffffffff
printf("%x\n", (unsigned char)~0); // ff
```

the expressions `(char)~0)` and `(unsigned char)~0)` are converted to the type `int` due to the integer promotions.

In the used system the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char`. So the sign bit in this expression is propagated when the expression is promoted to the type `int`.

On the other hand, before the integer promotions this expression `(unsigned char)~0` has the type `unsigned char` due to the casting to the unsigned type. So neither sign bit is propagated when the expression is promoted to the type `int`.

Pay attention to that the conversion specifier `x` is applied to objects of the type unsigned int. So the first call of printf should be written like

```
printf("%x\n", ( unsigned int )(char)~0);
```